# What does "Reset Imminent" mean on bosses like these?

Tags: lost-ark

At first I assumed maybe it had something to do with it getting out of its arena range and then returning to its home location, similar to how some other games handle enemies too far out of their area, but this warning still occurs even when the boss is at the center of the arena. I can't tell if it's a dps check or something but the boss never reset at all, so I'm wondering what this means...

[image]

What does "Reset Imminent" mean?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, the prompt shows up when they get closer to the edge of their circle (I have seen one prompt show up as they just walked towards it) - there's a thin, glowing line surrounding the boss that indicates their area they'll fight within.

If they go outside of that they can reset to full health back in the middle. But I have not seen one or heard of one reset from just taking too long.

I have seen it briefly pop up when they aren't too close to the edge, and I have yet to see a boss actually reset without going outside of their zone - across any of the zone bosses that I've killed so far. I *have* seen one reset after going outside of its zone.